# Stata time conversion

Tags: variables, time, stata

I am working with a int (%8.0g) variable called `timeinsecond` that was badly coded. For example, a value for this variable 12192 should mean 3h 23min 12s.  I'm trying to create a new variable that based on the value of time would give me the total time expressed in HH:MM:SS.

In the example I mentioned, the new variable would be 03:23:12.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stata uses the units of milliseconds for date-times, so assuming that no time here is longer than 24 hours, you can use the principle here:

```
. clear

. set obs 1 
number of observations (_N) was 0, now 1

. gen timeinsecond = 12192 

. gen double wanted = timeinsecond * 1000

. format wanted %tcHH:MM:SS 

. list 

     +---------------------+
     | timein~d     wanted |
     |---------------------|
  1. |    12192   03:23:12 |
     +---------------------+
```

All documented at `help datetime`.

Comment: Thank you so much. Unfortunately I cannot resolve all my problems... When I generate a Kaplan Meyer survivor graph with the new variable "wanted", Stata still doesn't use the new format (HH:MM:SS) for x axis.... (stset wanted; sts graph, by(Drug))

Comment: Post that as a new question with a real(istic) data example please.